# When I quit xmonad, how can I make it shut down applications nicely?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, shutdown, xmonad

When I quit xmonad (Shift-Mod-Q), it kills all my running applications. This results in me losing my recent terminal history in gnome-terminal and in Chromium complaining on the next start up that it was shut down incorrectly.

How can I make xmonad quit the applications nicely?

I am running xmonad on ubuntu 12.04. I am not running it on top of gnome-session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install wmctrl using your package manager.

Then use this little script to close all of your windows gracefully

> for win in $(wmctrl -l | awk '{print $1}'); do
>
> wmctrl -i -c $win
>
> done

Add this to your quit keybinding before xmonad exits itself.

I tested this with firefox and when I stared it next it, started correctly like I closed the window myself.

Comment: I ended up running XMonad on top of XFCE instead, so I don't have this problem anymore. I'm going to trust you that it works and accept this answer without testing it.

Comment: You will need to enable http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Hooks-EwmhDesktops.html in order for this to work.

Comment: @FlorianMayer link is broken, but you can easily see how to rend `XMonad` EWMH compliant at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Hooks-EwmhDesktops.html . Basically, inside your `xmonad.hs` file, you have to `import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops` and replace `xmonad $ def` with `xmonad $ ewmh def`